# Group by and nesting result in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, nested

im working in an API and i want to order by id DESC but i want to group by client_id too, so i could have all the questions from same clients ordered, nesting the results:

This is my code:

models.py

```
class QuestionsModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    publication_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publication_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member_id = models.IntegerField()
    client_id = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'questions'
```

serializers.py

```
class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QuestionsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class QuestionsAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ''
        member_id = self.request.query_params.get('member_id')
        
        if member_id is not None and member_id.isnumeric():
            queryset = QuestionsModel.objects.filter(member_id=member_id).order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

Result:

```
    {
    "id": 848484,
    "publication_id": 4444,
    "publication_title": "Title publication",
    "publication_link": "Link",
    "question": "This is a test question",
    "member_id": 123456,
    "client_id": 500
    }
```

What i want: Group questions by client_id, so desire output JSON could be:

```
{
"client_id": 500,
"question" : [
    "id": 848484,
    "publication_id": 4444,
    "publication_title": "Title publication",
    "publication_link": "Link",
    "question": "This is a test question",
    "member_id": 123456,
    "client_id": 500
 ],
[
    "id": 848485,
    "publication_id": 4445,
    "publication_title": "Title publication",
    "publication_link": "Link",
    "question": "This is a test question",
    "member_id": 123456,
    "client_id": 500
]
}
```

Notes: I'm using SQL Server as db engine.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 'one-to-many' relation between Clients and Questions, I would advise creating a Client model and having a foreign key relation between questions and their client. You can then leverage DRF's model serializers and nested relations more easily.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Here is a simplified version of what I think you are trying to achieve:

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(to=Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='questions')
```

serializers.py

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id','question']


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['id','questions']
```

views.py

```
class ClientList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
```

If I hook this view up to a URL and call GET on it, the resulting data structure is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "question": "questions 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "question": "questions2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "question": "questions3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm not sure who you intend to consume your API, but as someone who works with REST a lot, this data structure is more intuitive to me than the one you proposed. This is a list of client objects (albeit containing only one in this example), with a nested list of question objects below. Expand your models and refine your queryset as you see fit!